# Doctrine 2: Saving Entity in Complex Relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have the following relationships within my doctrine entities:

**FavoriteRecipe**

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="favoriteRecipes")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Recipe", inversedBy="favoriteRecipes")
 */
private $recipe;
```

**Recipe**

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="FavoriteRecipe", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $favoriteRecipes;
```

**User**

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="FavoriteRecipe", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $favoriteRecipes;
```

In one of my controllers I have the following code:

```
$favoriteRecipe = new \Entities\FavoriteRecipe();
$favoriteRecipe->setRecipe($recipe);
$favoriteRecipe->setUser($user);
$this->_em->persist($favoriteRecipe);
$this->_em->flush();
```

But this throws an exception with the following message:

> A new entity was found through a relationship that was not configured
>   to cascade persist operations:
>   Entities\User@00000000408bd010000000007cb1380e. Explicitly persist the
>   new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the
>   relationship.

**How can I correctly create and save a `FavoriteRecipe` entity?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you set the cascade option for all your relational entities? This is done by setting the cascade property for example: cascade={"persist", "remove"}

Maybe this page:https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: To which side of the association do I add the cascade option? The owning side or the inverse side?

Comment: It depends on the behavior you want but in your situation I think the inverse side. I would say try it, and look what happends in the database.

Comment: And i would add "and come back here to share you findings". People helped you, don't forget to help people :)