# How can I make Doctrine 2 ignore new entities found through relationships?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

For example, I have the following two classes (getters / setters omitted for brevity), which are linked both ways in mapping:

```
class Form
{
    private $elements = array();

    public function addElement($element)
    {
        $this->elements[] = $element
        $element->setForm($this);
    }
}

class Element
{
    private $form;
    private $name;
}

<one-to-many field="elements" target-entity="Element" mapped-by="form"/>

<many-to-one field="form" target-entity="Form" inversed-by="elements">
    <join-column name="formId" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" on-update="CASCADE"/>
</many-to-one>
```

If I do the following; adding two elements to the form, but only persisting one element, what I want to happen is for the unpersisted element to be ignored completely by the Entity Manager, but the other element and the form to be inserted into the database:

```
$form = new Form;
$em->persist($form);

$element = new Element;
$element->setName('firstName');
$form->addElement($element);
$em->persist($element);

$element2 = new Element;
$element2->setName('lastName');
$form->addElement($element2);

$em->flush();
```

At the moment get the following error:

```
exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'A new entity was found through the relationship 'Form#elements' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity Element@0000000019217f52000000009c20d747. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Element#__toString()' to get a clue
```

As far as I can tell there are no cascade options to ignore new entities (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) and using a preUpdate lifecycle callback to remove the offending entities from the $elements array also doesn't work because the exception is thrown before the callbacks are run.

Is there are any way around this?

Comment: Here is the answer to same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319370/doctrine-2-saving-entity-in-complex-relationship

Comment: That's not the same - he wants to automatically save the new entity. I want it to be ignored and not saved.

Comment: Tried to set nullable=true on the joinColumn?

Answer (score 0):

Try yo flush only the entities you want:

```
$form = new Form;
$em->persist($form);
$em->flush($form);

$element = new Element;
$element->setName('firstName');
$form->addElement($element);
$em->persist($element);
$em->flush($element);

//ignored element
$element2 = new Element;
$element2->setName('lastName');
$form->addElement($element2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is the only relevant page for this problem I could find, I'll add my own solution that I came up with. (In my project it's also basically a form with answers, where I manually save answers that were updated, but incomplete answers should not be saved to the database when persisting the form.)

Basically you create two properties for the relation: One that will only be used to load the persisted related elements (`$subEntities`) and one that will be made available to the public (`$chachedSubEntities`).

This `$cachedSubEntities` member will be initialized with the persisted subEntities the first time you call `getSubEntities`.

```
class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SubEntity", mappedBy="parent", indexBy="id")
     */
    protected $subEntities;
    
    protected $cachedSubEntities;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subEntities = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    
    public function getSubEntities()
    {
        if (is_null($this->cachedSubEntities)) {
            $this->cachedSubEntities = new ArrayCollection($this->subEntities->toArray());
        }
        return $this->cachedSubEntities;
    }
}
```